# iText gradient issue in landscape

Tags: itext

Having used gradients in iText in the past with no problems, suddenly i have an issue with it not working and narrowed it down to the fact that
this time i am working in landscape, (technically PageSize.A4.rotate()). The rotate() makes something happen that prevents the gradient from working as expected (by me).

To illustrate, i've adapted the example of the pink-blue triangle http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-shading-pattern-custom-shape

```java
public class GradientProblem {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {
        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(new File("gradientProblem.pdf")));
        doc.open();
        drawSexyTriangle(writer);
        doc.setPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());
        doc.newPage();
        drawSexyTriangle(writer);
        doc.close();
    }

    private static void drawSexyTriangle(PdfWriter writer) {
        PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
        float x = 36;
        float y = 400;
        float side = 70;
        PdfShading axial = PdfShading.simpleAxial(writer, x, y, x + side, y, BaseColor.PINK, BaseColor.BLUE);
        PdfShadingPattern shading = new PdfShadingPattern(axial);
        canvas.setShadingFill(shading);
        canvas.moveTo(x,y);
        canvas.lineTo(x + side, y);
        canvas.lineTo(x + (side / 2), (float)(y + (side * Math.sin(Math.PI / 3))));
        canvas.closePathFillStroke();
    }
}
```

Notice that the shading of the triangle on the first page is pink-blue, but on the second rotated page is just blue.

- is this a bug, or expected behaviour?
- if expected, how does the co-ordinate system work, ie what do the x0, y0, x1, y1 parameters to simpleAxial really mean?

The obvious work-around is to construct the appropriate page-size without rotation.

However using rotate() appears to be the advised approach, and when i have gradient code deep inside a re-useable table or cell event i can't really know how the page was constructed (or can i, i just don't know how?)

Any tips or insight would be much appreciated.

PS: tried iText 5.5.8 and 5.5.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that while itext content adding functionalities **do** take the page rotation into account (they translate the given coordinates so that in the rotated page *x* goes right and *y* goes up and the origin is in the lower left), the shading pattern definitions (which are *not* part of the page content but externally defined) **don't**.

Thus, you have to make the shading definition rotation aware, e.g. like this:

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(new File(RESULT_FOLDER, "gradientProblem.pdf")));
doc.open();
drawSexyTriangle(writer, false);
doc.setPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());
doc.newPage();
drawSexyTriangle(writer, true);
doc.close();
```

with

```
private static void drawSexyTriangle(PdfWriter writer, boolean rotated)
{
    PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
    float x = 36;
    float y = 400;
    float side = 70;
    PdfShading axial = rotated ?
            PdfShading.simpleAxial(writer, PageSize.A4.getRight() - y, x, PageSize.A4.getRight() - y, x + side, BaseColor.PINK, BaseColor.BLUE)
            : PdfShading.simpleAxial(writer, x, y, x + side, y, BaseColor.PINK, BaseColor.BLUE);
    PdfShadingPattern shading = new PdfShadingPattern(axial);
    canvas.setShadingFill(shading);
    canvas.moveTo(x,y);
    canvas.lineTo(x + side, y);
    canvas.lineTo(x + (side / 2), (float)(y + (side * Math.sin(Math.PI / 3))));
    canvas.closePathFillStroke();
}
```

*([DrawGradient.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/content/DrawGradient.java#L48))*

Comment: Thanks! Under the rotation co-ordinates, is it rotated clockwise (so that 0,0 is top left with x now increasing down the page); or is it counter-clockwise (so that 0,0 is at bottom right with x increasing up the page) ?

Comment: The page **Rotate** entry (which you implicitly set by using a page size with rotation) contains "The number of degrees by which the page
shall be rotated **clockwise** when displayed or printed. The value
shall be a multiple of 90." Thus, iText internally for the content and the method above for the shading pattern have to counteract by a **counter-clockwise** rotation. Furthermore iText moves the origin left again, and so does the method above.